# Java Web Start Unable to launch application

Tags: java, eclipse, java-web-start, jnlp

I created a java application using Eclipse. After creating the application I wanted to be able to auto update. Therefore I tried to start using Java Web Start. This is my process of generating the Keystore, assigning the keystore to the jar file, creating the jnlp file, and uploading everything to my server.

I created a keystore by typing the following in the Command Prompt at my jar's location:

```
keytool -genkey -keystore NameOfKey -alias MyAliasName
```

I was prompted and answered the following:

```
password: password1
rePassword: password1
What is your first and last name? [Unknown]: John Smith
What is the name of your organizational unit? [Unknown]: Development
What is the name of your organization? [Unknown]: App Co
What is the name of your City or Location? [Unknown]: Dallas
What is the name of your State or Province? [Unknown]: Texas
What is the two-letter Country code for this unit? [Unknown]: US
Is CN=John Smith, OU=Development, O=App Co, L=Dallas, ST=Texas, C=US correct? [no]: yes

Enter key password for <MyAliasName>
    (RETURN if same as keystore password):
```

I pressed return. and the NameOfKey was created. 
Next I assigned the keystore to the jar file, by opening the command prompt navigating to the keystore’s location and putting in the following:

```
jarsigner -keystore NameOfKey MyApplication.jar MyAliasName

Enter Passphrase for keystore: password1
jar signed.
Warning:
The signer certificate will expire within six months.
No -tsa or -tsacert is provided and this jar is not timestamped. Without a times
tamp, users may not be able to validate this jar after the signer certificate's
expiration date (2014-08-27) or after any future revocation date.
```

My Myjnlp.jnlp file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://example.com/Java/" href="Myjnlp.jnlp">
    <information>
            <title>This is my Title</title>
            <vendor>App Co</vendor>
            <homepage href="http://example.com" />
            <description>Testing Testing</description>
    </information>
    <security>
            <all-permissions/>
        </security>
        <resources>
            <j2se version="1.6+" />
            <jar href="MyApplication.jar" />
        </resources>
    <application-desc main-class="org.eclipse.wb.swing.SwingAppWindow" />
</jnlp>
```

I store my MyApplication.jar, Myjnlp.jnlp, and NameOfKey on the my site located in http://example.com/Java/. I can go to http://example.com/Java/Myjnlp.jnlp I download the jnlp and when I try to run it I get the following error.

```
Unable to launch the application.

com.sun.deploy.net.JARSigningException: Found unsigned entry in resource: http://example.com/Java/MyApplication.jar
at com.sun.javaws.security.SigningInfo.check(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedResourcesHelper(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedResources(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareResources(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareAllResources(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: you need to replace the http://example.com with your own domain or server\s IP address, 192.168... in Jnlp file and store the jnlp file in that path.

Comment: Did you check that your jar was actually signed by jarsigner? You can check it by unzipping it, and opening its MANIFEST.MF. On a signed jar, there should be a Digest per class.